# Question about solution 8.5 Munkres

Tags: general-topology

I find a solution of problem 8.5 Munkres. I have a question about this solution.

Why if $h$ is a unique function by Theorem 8.4 (what is framed in blue), then it proves again that $h$ is unique (what is framed in red)?

[image]

Comment: I agree. Given that definition for $\rho,$ the uniqueness which the exercise is asking for is provided by Theorem 8.4. Where does this solution come from?

Comment: From the book : "Topology Second Edition by James Munkres Solutions Manual" by Dan Whitman

Comment: Well, it seems he did a (methodological) mistake. The solution is much simpler: https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-1/section-8-the-principle-of-recursive-definition/problem-5-solution/